# Has anyone had this Resharper 2019 space problem in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

i installed Resharper 2019 in VS 2019, and as you see below, when a method takes a string as an input, it creates this weird space as you can see marked in red!

has anyone had this issue? do you know how it can be solved?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any other extensions? How do you know it is ReSharper adding this space? When is this space being added? Have you tried disabling ReSharper? Does it only happen for methods that take a string parameter? Your question needs more detail.

Comment: @Piers Myers. No i didn't add any extensions, it is a fresh installation of windows 10 and VS 2019, i know it's Resharper because if i uninstall it, the problem goes away. 
Yes, it only happens with methods that take string as a parameter.

Comment: What is the name of the parameter to the PostAsync method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be the new [Parameter Name Hints feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html) recently added to ReSharper. You can configure this in Visual Studio under `Extensions`->`ReSarper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Editor`->`Parameter Name Hints`

[image]

I am not sure why the font size is so big, maybe you are using a high DPI display or multiple displays and ReSharper is not playing nicely, I think the next version will address this. If you have the 'Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities' option ticked in Visual Studio under `Options`->`Environment`->`General` try unticking it.

Comment: Unticking the "Show parameter name hints" solved it! Thanks a lot bro, i was just about to give up and uninstall Resharper.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in ReSharper 2019.1.x in presenting parameter hints. A workaround for this is mentioned in [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-475293)

> add the following line to GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings file
> (before `</wpf:ResourceDictionary>`) in %AppData%\JetBrains\Shared\vAny:
>
> `<s:String`
> `x:Key="/Default/Environment/IntraTextAdornmentsOptions/ScaleFactor/@EntryValue">0,8</s:String>`

-Edit: 0,8 can be 0.8 if you are using English US or UK Language on Windows.

Please note that this issue was fixed in [ReSharper 2019.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/).